# the controller doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi everyone at this time I created a new controller, view and helper called `Menuprestacionessociales`

I have all the files as I think it should be

menuprestacionessociales_controller.rb

```
class MenuprestacionessocialesController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @variable = "cualquier contenido"
    end
end
```

**menuprestacionessociales/index.html.erb**

```
<%= @variable %>
```

So I have a simple variable in my controller called `@variable` but if I try to show the content in the index, it doesn't show anything

Comment: By "doesn't show anything", do you mean you don't see "cualquier contenido"? or you see nothing in your browser, not even "Prestaciones Sociales"? You don't seem to be using `@variable` anywhere, and your `class="<%= @healthservices %>"` are suspicious to say the least!

Comment: Note that when naming your controller class `MenuprestacionessocialesController` should be `MenuPrestacionesSocialesController`. It follows best practices to capitalize that way.

Comment: I just want to see "cualquier contenido" I mean the content of the variable, the rest of the index content it's ok

Comment: Do the other variables like `@healthservices` or `@professionalrisks` show up?

Comment: At the moment those variables are not working because is not working even the variable @variable, so I'm trying with a simple value as you see just to show @variable="cualquier contenido" in the index.html.erb, and about what you said the name of the class should be working  because I have another this way and works ok, but in this case of the MenuprestacionessocialesController doesn't work the variables

Comment: The instance variables used in the view is not defined anywhere in the controller, neither is the ones used in the views defined in controller, the views bind to the controller methods so the instance variables defined in the controller methods are available to their respective views, your helper currently does not do anything either so it is not relevant in the question @jason328 you forgot to mention that the CamelCasing would affect the file names too so file name would become <code>menu_prestaciones_sociales_controller.rb</code> for  <code> MenuPrestacionesSocialesController</code>

Comment: @bjhaid Correct about camel casing. My assumption was that the user would be aware of that, but thanks for bringing up anyways.

Comment: I updated the content of the post, is simple what I need, but is not working

Comment: @jason328 he does not seem to know what he his doing, so you might confuse him more if you don't specify <code>snake_case</code> for filename and <code>CamelCase</code> for class/module name

Answer (score 0):

Put `<%= @variable %>` somewhere in the `index.html.erb` file.

Comment: I did that in my index file, but not appear's the content

Comment: Edit the post and update the `index.html.erb` to what it looks like now.

Comment: I already did it, it's just a simple variable but doesn't work

Comment: @Andru1989 please post your new index.html.erb, and also check your <code>development.log</code> located in <code>project_path/log/development.log</code> for any exception(s) or error(s), or in the server logs that spools from <code>rails s</code>

Comment: if you add to `def index` a spew like `p 'FIXME'`, and you refresh your browser, do you see that spew? That's another way to diagnose if you are actually hitting that action at all...